# Is there an index function in yfinance for pulling previous years dividend? Or any dividend functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yahoo-finance, quantitative-finance, yfinance

```py
div_growth_rate = WMT.info['returnOnEquity'] * (1-WMT.get_info()['payoutRatio'])
div_growth_rate
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain dividends from yahoo finance using the `yfinance` library. Just do:

```py
import yfinance as yf
msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
msft.dividends
```

**Output:**

```
Date
2003-02-19    0.08
2003-10-15    0.16
2004-08-23    0.08
2004-11-15    3.08
2005-02-15    0.08
              ... 
2021-08-18    0.56
2021-11-17    0.62
2022-02-16    0.62
2022-05-18    0.62
2022-08-17    0.62
Name: Dividends, Length: 75, dtype: float64
```